# How to Implement a ListBox of Checkboxes in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listbox, checkbox

Although somewhat experienced with writing Winforms applications, the... "vagueness" of WPF still eludes me in terms of best practices and design patterns.

Despite populating my list at runtime, my listbox appears empty.

I have followed the simple instructions from [this helpful article](http://merill.net/2009/10/wpf-checked-listbox/) to no avail. I suspect that I'm missing some sort of `DataBind()` method where I tell the listbox that I'm done modifying the underlying list.

In my MainWindow.xaml, I have:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TopicList}" Height="177" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,173,0,0" Name="listTopics" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" Background="#0B000000">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In my code-behind, I have:

```
    private void InitializeTopicList( MyDataContext context )
    {
        List<Topic> topicList = ( from topic in context.Topics select topic ).ToList();

        foreach ( Topic topic in topicList )
        {
            CheckedListItem item = new CheckedListItem();
            item.Name = topic.DisplayName;
            item.ID = topic.ID;
            TopicList.Add( item );
        }
    }
```

Which, by tracing through, I know is being populated with four items.

**EDIT**

I have changed `TopicList` to an `ObservableCollection`. It still doesn't work.

```
    public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem> TopicList;
```

**EDIT #2**

I have made two changes that help:

In the .xaml file:

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

In the source code after I populate the list:

```
listTopics.DataContext = TopicList;
```

I'm getting a list, but it's not automagically updating the checkbox states when I refresh those. I suspect a little further reading on my part will resolve this.

Comment: Downvoter: exactly how does this question not show research effort, is unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection<Topic>` instead of `List<Topic>`

**Edit**

it implements INotifyCollectionChanged interface to let WPF know when you add/remove/modify items

**Edit 2**

Since you set `TopicList` in code, it should be a Dependency Property, not a common field

```
    public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem> TopicList {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem>)GetValue(TopicListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TopicListProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopicListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TopicList", typeof(ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

**Edit 3**

To see changes in items

1. implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in `CheckedListItem` (each setter should call `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(<property name as string>))` event)
2. or derive `CheckedListItem` from `DependencyObject`, and convert `Name`, `ID`, `IsChecked` to dependency properties
3. or update them totally (`topicList[0] = new CheckedListItem() { Name = ..., ID = ... }`)

Comment: Thanks to everybody who helped me cobble together a solution. It was your INotifyPropertyChanged suggestion that led me to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx which completed the solution.

Comment: ObservableCollection<Topic> will spot added/removed items, but it will not spot modified items

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `TopicList` is not an `ObservableCollection<T>` therefore when you add items no `INotifyCollection` changed is being fired to tell the binding engine to update the value.

Change your `TopicList` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` which will resolve the current issue. You could also populate the `List<T>` ahead of time and then the binding will work via OneWay; however `ObservableCollection<T>` is a more robust approach.

**EDIT:**

Your `TopicList` needs to be a property not a member variable; bindings require properties. It does **not** need to be a `DependencyProperty`.

**EDIT 2:**

Modify your `ItemTemplate` as it does not need to be a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

```
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be a DependencyProperty only if its value is set before first binding is done or container class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and calls PropertyChanged(...) on TopicList.set method

Comment: You should bind to the `IsSelected` property on `ListBoxItem`: `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}"` You should probably also set `IsHitTestVisible` and `IsFocusable` to false.

Answer (score 3):

First you dont need a HeirarchicalDataTemplate for this. Just regular DataTemplate as Aaron has given is enough.
Then you need to instantiate the TopicList ObservableCollection somewhere inside the constructor of the class. which makes the ObservableCollection alive even before you add data in to it And binding system knows the collection. Then when you add each and every Topic/CheckedListItem it will automatically shows up in the UI.

```
TopicList = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem>(); //This should happen only once

private void InitializeTopicList( MyDataContext context )
{
    TopicList.Clear();

    foreach ( Topic topic in topicList )
    {
        CheckedListItem item = new CheckedListItem();
        item.Name = topic.DisplayName;
        item.ID = topic.ID;
        TopicList.Add( item );
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this way you don't need `TopicList` dependency propertiy

Answer (score 3):

Others have already made useful suggestions (use an observable collection to get list-change notification, make the collection a property rather than a field).  Here are two they haven't:

1) Whenever you're having a problem with data binding, look in the Output window to make sure that you're not getting any binding errors.  You can spend a lot of time trying to fix the wrong problem if you don't do this.

2) Understand the role change notification plays in binding.  Changes in your data source can't and won't get propagated to the UI unless the data source implements change notification.  There are two ways to do this for normal properties:  make the data source derive from `DependencyObject` and make the bound property a dependency property, or make the data source implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the property's value changes.  When binding an `ItemsControl` to a collection, use a collection class that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (like `ObservableCollection<T>`), so that changes to the contents and order of the collection will get propagated to the bound control.  (Note that if you want changes to the items *in* the collection to get propagated to the bound controls, those items need to implement change notification too.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old question but I came to building custom Listbox which get the SelectedItems with built in select all / unselect all

[image]

**CustomListBox**

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
    {
        #region Constants

        public static new readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedItems), typeof(IList), typeof(CustomListBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(IList), OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public new IList SelectedItems
        {
            get => (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers

        private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((CustomListBox)d).OnSelectedItemsChanged((IList)e.OldValue, (IList)e.NewValue);
        }

        protected virtual void OnSelectedItemsChanged(IList oldSelectedItems, IList newSelectedItems)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
            SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, base.SelectedItems);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**ListBoxControl.cs**

public partial class ListBoxControl : UserControl
{
#region Constants

```
public static new readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Content), typeof(object), typeof(ListBoxControl),
                        new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static new readonly DependencyProperty ContentTemplateProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ContentTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ListBoxControl),
                         new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Items), typeof(IList), typeof(ListBoxControl),
                         new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedItems), typeof(IList), typeof(ListBoxControl),
                       new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemsChanged));

#endregion

#region Properties

public new DataTemplate ContentTemplate
{
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ContentTemplateProperty);
    set => SetValue(ContentTemplateProperty, value);
}

public IList Items
{
    get => (IList)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
}

public IList SelectedItems
{
    get => (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
}

#endregion

#region Constructors

public ListBoxControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

#endregion

#region Event Handlers

private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is not ListBoxControl || e.NewValue is not IList newValue)
    {
        return;
    }
     
    var mylist = (d as ListBoxControl).CustomList;

    foreach (var selectedItem in newValue)
    {
        mylist.UpdateLayout();
        if (mylist.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem) is ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem)
        {
            selectedListBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region Private Methods

private void CheckAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomList.SelectAll();
}

private void UncheckAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomList.UnselectAll();
}

#endregion
```

}

#endregion

**ListBoxControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.ListBoxControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControls"
             xmlns:str="Client.Properties"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             x:Name="this">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:CustomListBox  x:Name="CustomList" 
                             Grid.Row="0"   
                             Width="250"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             SelectionMode="Multiple"
                             Visibility="Visible"
                             MinHeight="25"
                             MaxHeight="400"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding  ElementName=this, Path =Items}"
                             SelectedItems="{Binding  ElementName=this, Path =SelectedItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <local:CustomListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptureWithin" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptureWithin" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </local:CustomListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <local:CustomListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <CheckBox Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding .}" ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=this, Path = ContentTemplate, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:CustomListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </local:CustomListBox>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"  
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button Click="CheckAll_Click"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        ToolTip="Check all">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="CheckAll.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>

                <Button         
                        Click="UncheckAll_Click"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        Visibility="Visible"
                        ToolTip="Unchecked all">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=this, Path = SelectedItems.Count}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="UncheckAll.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>

            </StackPanel>

            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path = SelectedItems.Count, StringFormat={x:Static str:Resources.STE_LABEL_X_ITEMS_CHECKED}, Mode=OneWay}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Foreground="White" />
        </Grid>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now you can use that custom control in any control or page and pass any content you want
EX : ConfigView.xaml

```
<UserControl ..
 xmlns:userControls="Client.UserControls"
..>

<userControls:ListBoxControl 
                    ShowCheckBox="True" 
                    MinHeight="25"
                    MaxHeight="400"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    Items="{Binding MyLists, Mode=OneWay}"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedMyLists,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <userControls:ListBoxControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name,StringFormat=' {0}'}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </userControls:ListBoxControl.ContentTemplate>
                </userControls:ListBoxControl>
```

**here we bind to the selected items and than do explicit casting to our model
ConfigViewViewModel**

```
private IList _myLists;
 public IList MyLists
        {
            get => _myLists;
            set
            {
                if (_myLists == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _myLists = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItems));
            }
        }
public IEnumerable<MyModel> SelectedItems => MyLists.Cast<MyModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

change your binding to

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TopicList}"
```