# Checking a select-all checkbox in WPF doesn't change other checkboxes in Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I implemented a `ListBox` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527286/how-to-implement-a-listbox-of-checkboxes-in-wpf/4527335) and [this](http://merill.net/2009/10/wpf-checked-listbox/). I bind my actual list of 29 objects to it and it works well.
In XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="WBauNrList" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Height="100" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Baunr}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In code:

```
datenpunktList = new ObservableCollection<Datenpunkt>();
foreach (var d in WerkstattList.DistinctBy(p => p.lokNr))
{
    var newd = new Datenpunkt() { Baunr = d.lokNr };
    datenpunktList.Add(newd);
}

WBauNrList.ItemsSource = datenpunktList;
```

### But the problem:

I want to have a select-all `CheckBoxes` to able the user to select and deselect all items. It works strangely!

After checking the `selectAll CheckBox`, all items will be checked that is not in the scope of the scrollbar (the list is scrolled), then I should scroll down and up to see that all items are checked.

XAML:

```
<CheckBox Name="selectAll" Click="selectAll_Click" >Secelct all</CheckBox>
```

Code:

```
private void selectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Datenpunkt item in WBauNrList.Items)
    {
        item.IsChecked = true ;
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea what to do.

Thanks in advance, Mo

Comment: Have you implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the `IsChecked`property of your `Datenpunkt` class?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom 

no. should it look like this?

public static readonly DependencyProperty isCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

Comment: If you are binding a property to your xaml and you want your ui to be updated when the property is changed via code you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

No, that would be a dependency property.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom . i will check it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property `IsChecked` implementation could look like this.

```
public class Datenpunkt : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            Notify("IsChecked");
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [MSDN INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) page for more information.